# Calc Libreoffice : How to create diagram using hours in X axis

Tags: date, time, diagram, libreoffice, calc

I want to create a diagram showing a quantity (Y axis) according to a date/time (X axis).
time scale must be preserved on the X axis the visual gap between 08:00:00 and 09:00:00 is not the same as between 08:00:00 and 12:00:00)
My data :
Date    Qté
01/01/2023 06:00    200
01/01/2023 07:00    250
01/01/2023 19:00    200

Calc (and Excel) seems to be unable to use gap less than a day ?
How can I resolve this ?

I tried to replace tha date of the last line by a string. Diagram is better, but time scale is wrong and I have a string in X axis (all date seems to be considered as string)

I expect a diagram with X axis showing dates and time and gap between date/time correct

Answer (score 0):

Rightclick on the graph, choose 'Format Axis', then 'Scale' to 'TEXT' (not to Date, because there is option to choose for Hours....

[image]
Picture taken from Libreoffice 7.6.2

Comment: Won't work :  time scale will NOT be preserved on the X axis the visual gap between 08:00:00 and 09:00:00 is not the same as between 08:00:00 and 12:00:00). I do not have a quantity each hour